# Saving YouTube video with VLC fails - only creates 1kb file with header

Tags: vlc

I am using VLC 3.0.18, and trying to save a YouTube video.

I can watch the video, using VLC., but when I try to convert or stream, regardless of which checkboxes I pick, the created file (eg "JunkVLC.MP4") has not content other than a header, and is 1kb in size.

Obviously, I am doing something wrong with the capture.

To my surprise, some check boxes that I would expect would not display the video as the conversion occurs, does so anyway.   If I attempt to do only the first 5 seconds, that request does nothing different -- the video displays to the full length.

If I merely play, it works, but ignores the stop at 5 seconds.  The code it autogenerates is:  :network-caching=1000 :stop-time=5.000

The VLC Log, is always empty -- even though I have enabled logging -- which offers no clues... whether I set it to default, debug or anything else.

The [short] output file looks like this (with NULs stuck here/there):
 moov   lmvhd    àÏåÃàÏåÃ _                                                @                                 ,udta   $©enc   vlc 3.0.18 stream output

Nothing is dumped in to the output file, beyond this header.

The media and codec info looks normal -- it is playing after all.

I am perplexed, as it is behaving as if ... well ... as if the more complex utility of VLC will not behave ... :(
I've uninstalled and cleared the remnants of VLC and re-installed the 3.0.18 64 version on to my windows 11 nifty box

Guidance appreciate in advance ...

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question. Maybe you wanted [superuser](https://superuser.com), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), or [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)